# SAS: How many days in year

Tags: sas

Does anybody knows the SAS function, which could return the year days count by the given date?

For example:

```
input value - date,
output value - days in the year(date)
```

Comment: You want the amount of days that have passed since Jan 1? Like Jan 3 would return 3 and Feb 3 would return 34?

Comment: I woul like to see the amount of days in the year since Jan 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the example from [the docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000530603.htm) and edited it to match your request

```
data _null;
   startdate='01jan14'd;
   enddate=DATE();
   actual=datdif(startdate, enddate, 'act/act');
   put actual;
run;
```

This should output `160` because that is the amount of days between today and Jan 1 (not counting today)

The start date is Jan 1 '14
The end date is DATE() which is 'today'

This uses the datdif function that is explained in detail in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since SAS [dates](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm) are just numbers...you can manipulate them by simply adding and subtracting them.

```
Data _null_;
 Diff= today() - '01Jan2014'd;
 Put Diff=;
Run;
```

Returns 160 in the log.